# How to fix an improper request in HAProxy

Tags: haproxy

We have several (100+) clients in the field with a bug in the HTTP request.  The request was previously working when directly routed to our Windows Server, but now with it fails with HAProxy v1.7 in front of it.

Here is an example request: 
GET /index.aspx HTTP/1.1 \nHost: host\n\n

There is an extra space after the HTTP version before the \n.

Here is a snapshot of the relevant config.

frontend http_port_80
        bind *:80
        mode http
        reqrep (.*)\ HTTP/1.1\ (.*)     \1\ HTTP/1.1\2
        option forwardfor
        option accept-invalid-http-request
        stats enable
        use_backend cert_update if is_updater
        use_backend getConsoleHTTP if is_getconsole
        default_backend schedule_server

I have tried rewriting the request to remove the extra space and set the option accept-invalid-http-request to address the issue, but we still receive the same error.

{
    type: haproxy,
    timestamp: 1506545591,
    termination_state: PR-,
    http_status:400,
    http_request:,
    http_version:,
    remote_addr:192.168.1.1,
    bytes_read:187,
    upstream_addr:-,
    backend_name:http_port_80,
    retries:0,
    bytes_uploaded:92,
    upstream_response_time:-1,
    upstream_connect_time:-1,
    session_duration:2382,
    termination_state:PR
}

Does anyone have any ideas of how to fix the malformed request prior to haproxy rejecting it?

Comment: Perhaps malformed request (client code) needs to be fixed instead of hacking the HA proxy configuration. #techdebt

Comment: I do agree with this statement, but the clients have been working for years and not all of the clients are easily fixed.  These clients are all over the country and not all are accessible to be fixed.